# How to fix garbage value in a date string array in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to format the date to MM/DD/YYYY. I want to add a '0' character when a single-digit appears. I keep getting a smiley character at the end of the month string. How to resolve this?
Note: the year ranges from 2019-2021

input:

COM 629

6/30/2021
6/29/2021
6/28/2021
6/25/2021

6/9/2021

6/5/21

output:

COM 629

6☻/30/2021
6☻/29/2021
6☻/28/2021
6☻/25/2021
6☻/09/2021

6☻/05/2021

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef double ohlc[8];
typedef char datelength[11];

void DateInput(datelength date[], datelength newdate[], int nrowsdata, int i);
void FormatDate(datelength date[], datelength newdate[], int nodate);

int main()
{
    char name[6]; //company name
    long int nrowsdata; 
    int i; //number of rows of data and i as counter for loops

    scanf("%s", name);  //scans the name of the company
    scanf("%ld", &nrowsdata); //scans the number of rows indicated
    printf("%s %ld", name, nrowsdata); //prints the name and number of rows indicated 
    printf("\n\n");
    datelength newdate[nrowsdata+1];
    datelength date[nrowsdata+1]; // 1d string array for date with the size of nrowsdata+1
    
    for (i = 0; i < nrowsdata; i++)
    {
        DateInput(date, newdate, nrowsdata, i);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
void DateInput(datelength date[], datelength newdate[], int nrowsdata, int i) // gets the date from the data from a specific row within the 1st column
{

    scanf("%s", date[i]);
    /*int k;
    printf("\n");
    for(k=0; k < strlen(date[i]); k++)
    {
        printf("%c", date[i][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");*/
    FormatDate(date, newdate, i); // this function is called with parameters.
}

void FormatDate(datelength date[], datelength newdate[], int nodate)
{
    char month[3], day[3], year[5]; // will contain the MM, DD, and YYYY
    
    
    int i, j = 1, k;
    
    int count = 0; //counter for the month,day,year to store the characters
    
    char newmonth[3]; //will contain the formatted MM ex. 5 > 05
    char newday[3]; //will contain the formatted DD ex. 5 > 05
    char newyear[5]; //will contain the formatted YYYY ex. 19 > 2019

    int stringlength = strlen(date[nodate]);
    
    for (i = 0; i <= stringlength; i++) //a linear search 
    {
        if(date[nodate][i] == '/') // slash acting as a delimiter 
        {
            j++; //moves to the next stage. for example, when done storing the month, it will proceed to store for day and so on.
            count = 0; // resets the count
        }
        else 
        {
            if (j == 1)
            {
                printf("%d \n", strlen(month));
                printf("%c %d before\n", month[count], count);
                printf("%c %d before\n", month[1], 1);
                printf("%c %d before\n", date[nodate][1], 1);
                month[count] = date[nodate][i]; //will be storing the characters before slash
                printf("%d \n", strlen(month));
                printf("%c %d after\n", month[count], count);
                printf("%d \n", strlen(month));
                printf("%c %d after\n", month[1], 1);
                printf("%c %d after\n", date[nodate][1], 1);
                
            }
            
            if (j == 2)
            {
                day[count] = date[nodate][i]; //will be storing the characters before slash
            }
               
            if (j == 3)
            {
                year[count] = date[nodate][i]; //will be storing the characters until it encounters the null byte
            }
            count++; //accumulates the count
        }
        
        
    }
  
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
 
    if(strlen(month) == 1) // this will detect whether the month string has only 1 character. for example, 5. 
    {
        strcpy(newmonth, "0");
        strcat(newmonth, month);    //the month string will be added to the newmonth string ex. 0 + 5 = 05
    }
    else if(strlen(month) == 2)// if the month already has 2 characters. for example, 05
    {
        strcpy(newmonth, month);//the month string will be copied to the newmonth string
    }
    
    if(strlen(day) == 1) // this will detect whether the day string has only 1 character. for example, 5.
    {
        strcpy(newday, "0");
        strcat(newday, day);     //the day string will be added to the newday string ex. 0 + 5 = 05
    }
    else if(strlen(day) == 2)// if the day already has 2 characters. for example, 05
    {       
        strcpy(newday, day); //the day string will be copied to the newday string   
    }

    if(strlen(year) == 2) // this will detect whether the year string has only 1 character. for example, 19. 
    {
        strcpy(newyear, "20");
        strcat(newyear, year);  //the year string will be added to the newyear string ex. 20 + 19 = 2019
    }
    else if(strlen(year) == 4)// if the year already has 4 characters. for example, 2019
    {
        strcpy(newyear, year); //the year string will be copied to the newday string
    }
    
    strcpy(newdate[nodate], newmonth); //temp will be overwritten by the month string. therefore, containing the month string.
    
    strcat(newdate[nodate], "/"); //temp will be then added with a slash
    
    strcat(newdate[nodate], newday); //temp will be added with newday string
    
    strcat(newdate[nodate], "/"); //temp will be then added with a slash
    
    strcat(newdate[nodate], newyear); //temp will be added with newyear string
    //The result: 05/05/2019
    
    printf("%s", newdate[nodate]);
    
    
}
```

Comment: Since `j` starts at `1`, if your first character isn't a slash, you do `strlen(month)`. But `month` hasn't been assigned any value yet. So that array doesn't even contain a string and passing it to `strlen` is undefined behavior. Before you can pass a pointer or array to `strlen`, you *must* ensure it points to or contains a valid string.

Comment: TLDR: you need to properly manage the terminating `'\0'` for strings.

Comment: Please get into the habit of using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) unless there is a very good reason not to, (_ie_ your professor told you to.)

Answer (score 1):

Validate the date by parsing it, reformat it by printing it:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void scrutinize_date(char *mdy)
{
unsigned mm,dd,yy;

int rc;
rc = sscanf(mdy, "%u/%u/%u", &mm, &dd, &yy);
if (rc !=3) { return; } // handle error here ?
if (yy < 100) yy += (yy <=21) ? 2000 : 1900;

sprintf(mdy, "%02u/%02u/%04u", mm, dd, yy);

return;
}


int main(void)
{

char the_date[20] = "1/31/21";

printf("Before:%s\n", the_date);
scrutinize_date(the_date);
printf("After:%s\n", the_date);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (yy < 100) yy += (yy <=21) ? 2000 : 1900;` would mean to make it the 1900s if the 2-digit year is greater than 21? I think you only need `if (yy < 100) yy += 2000;`, given "the year ranges from 2019 to 2021"

Comment: It is a feature!11!!!!1 (at least, some people actually *read* the code ...) And: it is rather simple to change it. (it is also a homework-guard)

Comment: I don't understand. It is your intent to make years beyond 2021 in the past? That doesn't scale if used beyond this year, granted we cannot determine the century given 2 digits. It seems more necessary to account for use in the future than to assume all other dates are in the past. I realize this is nitpicking beyond the scope of the OP question, so whatever. Your code works under the given conditions.

Comment: I could have tired to produce a Finite State Machine (excellent speed, excellent homework-guard!), but I was too lazy.